# How to filter data using a Dimension values in R?

Tags: r, google-analytics

I want to get Custom data from GA using R, for a dimension `ga:productSKU` using limited values only, but every time when i use

```
get_ga(id, metrics = met, dimensions = dim,
       start.date = '7daysAgo', end.date = 'today')
```

It gives data for all the products.

How can i filter out values from GA only i require and not corresponding to all the elements?. I have tried `list_filters()` function but i does no good and when i tried

```
get_ga(id, metrics = met,dimensions = dim,
       start.date = '7daysAgo', end.date = 'today',
       filters = ga:productSKU%3D%3D1435678)

Error: unexpected symbol in "get_ga(id,metrics = met,dimensions = dim,start.date = '7daysAgo',end.date = 'today', filters=ga:productSKU%3D%3D1435678"
```

where 1435678 is a productSKU i get an error.

Comment: Please see `get_ga` help file, your argument specification is way off. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/29607913/322912 on how to specify filters.

Comment: @Roman, I have stored all the required arguements in vectors and using them directly to get data, By the way thanks for the help it, I found what i was lacking.

Comment: Consider posting the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

`filters` param should be a character string:

```
get_ga(id, metrics = met,dimensions = dim,
       start.date = '7daysAgo', end.date = 'today',
       filters = "ga:productSKU==1435678")
```